# Messing with responsive web design, can't seem to make it work

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

What's happening is only the text is being changed, nothing else. I can't seem to manipulate divs when the screen size changes. And I've already set the relevant meta tag. The syntax is correct on the actual file on my desktop (as in, there are <style></style> tags on the web page (I'm doing everything on one page so I can reference things more easily. I'll move them to .css files later). I'm just trying to show what I have before you go diving into my code. Also, it's not all there, just the relevant stuff. If more than this is needed, do let me know, but one thing that isn't working (and this should tell you where I've messed up) is that the background-image isn't being added when the page is re-sized.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
@media screen and (max-width: 35em)  {
            body {
                font-size:10px;
                background-image: url("http://hdwallpapersx.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Awesome-Background-Hd-Wallpaper.jpg?c09534");
                background-color: #000;
                color: #F0F;
            }
            .logo {
                position:absolute;
                top:0px;
                left:0px;
                width:100%;
                height:50px;
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
                border:none;
                border-radius:0px;
                padding-top: 15px;
                font-size:15pt;
            }
            .bt {
                font-family: Tahoma;
                font-size:15pt;
            }
            nav {
                position:absolute;
                top: 51px;
                width: 100px;
                height: 30px;
            }
            nav ul li {
                padding-left: 10px;
                float: left;
            }
        }
        html {
            width: 100%;
        }
        body {
            width: 99%;
            background-color: #000;
            background-image: url("");
            background-size: 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            color: #CCC;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS it's interpreted from top to bottom. You've got 2 body rules on your css in the same media declaration so the last one will overwrite the properties previously declared on the first one. That's why you don't see the background image.

I recommend you to declare your rules in hierarchical order to avoid this kind of troubles.

Comment: So do I need to set a rule for every display size then? For instance, set a rule for min-width in contrast to max-width? Rather than just placing it out in the open?

Comment: Media queries are conditional rules that must overwrite main rules previously declared

Comment: here's an [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/duoBq), resize the screen and see how values are overwritten. A responsive layout does not means that you have to code al with @media declarations, just overwrite what it's necesary.

Comment: Got it working! Thanks for that, I'd have never guessed that I had to set up rules that aren't global. Thanks ^_^